# Filtering dataset with multiple conditions for monotherapy

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have this dataset which contains `patient_id`, `diagnosis_date`, `diagnosis`, `trt_date`, and `drug_code`.

```
# Create the dataset
data <- data.frame(
  patient_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 7),
  diagnosis_date = as.Date(c("1/9/10", "1/9/10", "1/9/10", 
                             "1/9/10", "1/11/10", "1/11/10", 
                             "1/9/10", "1/9/10"), format = "%m/%d/%y"),
  diagnosis = c("breast cancer", "breast cancer", "breast cancer", 
                "breast cancer", "breast cancer", "breast cancer", 
                "breast cancer", "breast cancer"),
  trt_date = as.Date(c("1/20/10", "1/20/10", "1/21/10", 
                       "1/21/10", "1/29/10", "1/30/10", 
                       "1/25/10", "1/26/10"), format = "%m/%d/%y"),
  drug_code = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A")
)
```

Here are the conditions for filtering:

- Patient id 1, has first treatment date of 1/20/10 and received drug A, but also received drug B on the same date (second line of observation). This is called first line combo therapy with drug A and B, which we will need to filter out . So patient id 1 will be **filtered out**.
- Patient id 5, has first treatment date of 1/29/10 and received only drug B, this is called first line monotherapy with drug B. So patient id 5 will be kept.
- Patient id 7 has first treatment date of 1/25/10 and received only drug A, this is called first line monotherapy with drug A.

As a result, I want observations that only have first line monotherapy with drug A and first line monotherapy with drug B, but not first line combo therapy with drug A and B. So patient id 7 will be kept.

So the desired output would look like:

```
patient_id    diagnosis_date     diagnosis          trt_date    drug_code
5             2010-01-11         breast cancer      2010-01-29  B
5             2010-01-11         breast cancer      2010-01-30  A
7             2010-01-09         breast cancer      2010-01-25  A
7             2010-01-09         breast cancer      2010-01-26  A
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please don't delete questions after getting an answer. Leave them around so other people can benefit in the future. (By posting here [you licensed this question under a Creative Commons license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). It's not yours to delete.)

Comment: P.S. If the reason you deleted the question was accidentally including actual patient data, you should [edit] the question to include fake patient data instead, and then flag the post for moderator attention explaining that you would like the initial revisions containing the patient data redacted.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  filter(lapply(list(drug_code), length) == 1, .by = c(patient_id, trt_date))

#>   patient_id diagnosis_date     diagnosis   trt_date drug_code
#> 1          5     2010-01-11 breast cancer 2010-01-29         B
#> 2          5     2010-01-11 breast cancer 2010-01-30         A
#> 3          7     2010-01-09 breast cancer 2010-01-25         A
#> 4          7     2010-01-09 breast cancer 2010-01-26         A
```